# Can you no longer sell mastered items in Infinity Blade 2?

Tags: infinity-blade-2

In the first game, you could sell any item that wasn't equipped, including mastered items.

Which made a lot of sense, as you'd use an item until you mastered it, earning a skill point, and then sell it and apply the money to a better weapon.

In the new game, I don't seem to have the option to sell a mastered item.  That seems like a strange strategic change - it means when an item is near mastery, you need to decide if you want to keep it till mastered for a point, or sell it for gold.   Is that really the case?   It would seem to create annoying dilemmas.   If you wind up with an incredibly valuable item, like the infinity blade, it's basically crazy not to sell it right before it's mastered.  If you master it, you trade a huge money opportunity for one point.   But in the old game, I could keep it for its abilities, and use it, knowing I could sell it later if I want to.

Am I missing something?

UPDATE:  This may be a more specific version of [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/39865/16), but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can only sell items you have duplicates of.**

This appears to be confirmed by an Epic exec in [this tweet](https://mobile.twitter.com/#!/MarkRein/status/142261347814621184).

This feels *a little* less like a balance improvement than a way to increase revenue from in-app gold sales, but given the value in the game to start with, and the fact that it's still not necessary to buy anything in-game to have fun, it's hard to get too annoyed.

Answer (score 6):

The new update in the past week or two expanded this functionality.

Now you can sell a weapon...

- If you have two of them
- Or if you have mastered it

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is mastered your weapon, and when you about to sell it, make sure you unequip your weapon. You should then have the option to sell it.